# Google apps script requires permissions that are already granted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

Here's the function in question:

```
function GetResponseDate(confirmation) {

  var threads = GmailApp.search(confirmation);
  var initialResponse;
  if(threads.length!=0){
   initialResponse = threads[0].getMessages()[0].getDate(); 
  }
  else{
    initialResponse = "none";
  }

  return initialResponse;

}
```

Here's the manifest:

```
{  
  "oauthScopes":[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify" 
    ],
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

The implementation is just

```
= GetResponseDate("12345")
```

within a cell.

I've granted all of the permissions requests that have popped up (whether by default, or the additional ones I added in the manifest file), but I still get the sheets error:

```
The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/) (line 3).
```

Comment: `GmailApp.search(query)` requires the scope: `https://mail.google.com/`  Even though the error message lists all those other scopes, they won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That was the default permission that was requested, and I confirmed it and then received this error. Now, adding it to the manifest and approving again, the same error shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using ``GetResponseDate`` as a custom function, such error occurs because from the official document, ``If your custom function throws the error message You do not have permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.`` [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) and [Ref2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts) If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Oh, thank you I had seen a few examples that I thought indicated that this was possible, my mistake. Is running the function as a menu item that populates cells a good alternative? It seems strange that of all places for google to determine permission can't be requested, cell formulas are the cutoff.

Comment: I think it's possible. When you run the script from the custom menu, the script works by authorizing the scopes which are using with the script. In your case, it's ``https://mail.google.com/`` as [mentioned by Alan Wells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799257/google-apps-script-requires-permissions-that-are-already-granted#comment100153660_56799257). And also, in this case, ``GetResponseDate`` is required to be modified for retrieving values from cells and running the script for each value.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Alan Wells and Tanaike (though I can't upvote them because my account is new).

Solution is: individual cell formulas can't request permissions, and the correct permission to request is `https://mail.google.com/`. One workaround is: execute script as a menu item instead of within a cell (though it needs to be modified to interpret and output to cells).